# use object in c# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I use dictionary in my program like this

```
Dictionary<string, List<Term>>
```

which Term is object from class has two fields (name , id)
I need add new object into dictionary  where the name of new object is not found in the dictionary...
if the field name in new object is existent as name of old object I will not add it..
can you help me 
the code I use is

```
 foreach (string term in terms)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(term))
        {
            dictionary.Add(term, new List<Term>());
        }

        Term TT=new Term(i,name);
        if (!dictionary[term].Contains(TT))
        {
            dictionary[term].Add(TT);


        }
```

this code dosn't work exactly..

Comment: What is "dont work exactly"? What error do you get or what is the result?

Comment: What's the problem? You need to tell us what's not working.

Comment: What's `i` and `name`? I don't see them declared anywhere.

Comment: The only thing I can see that might be wrong is the `new Term(i, name)` which was described with the two fields in the opposite order. And no closing brace on the `for` loop.

Comment: Is there a closing brace for the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    if (!dictionary[term].Contains(TT))
    {
        dictionary[term].Add(TT);
    }
```

The default behavior of [`List.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) if class `Term` does not implement `IEquatable<Term>` is to check for reference equality. Since the object you just constructed cannot already be in the list, `Contains` will always return `false` and the new `Term` will always be added.

One good solution would be to implement [`IEquatable<Term>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) in `Term` and specify the criteria you want for equality in the [`IEquatable<Term>.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) method.

Another solution (which is probably less desirable because it will only help this particular piece of code to work) is to change the test to

```
    // Change the t.name == TT.name test to whatever your idea
    // of "term X equals term Y" is
    if (dictionary[term].FindIndex(t => t.name == TT.name) == -1)
    {
        dictionary[term].Add(TT);
    }
```

Comment: or you can change the data structure to Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Term>> instead. the Contains operation for List is slow as it iterates through all the items.

Comment: @Can: Keep in mind - premature optimization is the root of all evil ;)

Comment: @ChrisWue Of course, but I think it makes sense to use a dictionary over list in places where you want to avoid duplicates, it's not completely about optimization, just about using the correct data structure for the problem.

Comment: THANK YOU very much the problem is solved by implement IEquatable<Term> in my class....as you said ..thank you all

Comment: @yamon: Nice to hear that. Since this answer solved your issue, please accept it by clicking the green check mark just below the number of votes on the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume a term object is identified by it's id. So you either need to implement `IEquatable<Term>` on the term class or look for the term with the right id like this:

```
if (!dictionary[term].Any(x => x.Id == TT.id))
{
    dictionary[term].Add(TT);
}
```

Note: Any is a Linq extension method, so you need to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Database producten

        Dictionary<string, double> producten = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        Console.WriteLine("Dit zijn de beschikbare producten");
        producten.Add("T-shirt", 45.35);
        Console.WriteLine("T-shirt");
        producten.Add("trui", 25.50);
        Console.WriteLine("trui");
        producten.Add("broek" , 90);
        Console.WriteLine("broek");

        //Einde database
        //Console.WriteLine(producten["trui"]);

        double tot = 0;
        bool boot = true;
        Dictionary<string, int> winkelmandje = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        while (boot)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wilt u een product toevoegen?, ja of nee?");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (answer == "ja")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Geef de naam van het product?:");
                string naam = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Hoeveel aantallen wenst u van dit product?:");
                int inthvl = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                winkelmandje.Add(naam, inthvl);

            }

            if (answer == "nee")
            {
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> product in winkelmandje)
                {
                    if (producten.ContainsKey(product.Key))
                    {
                        tot = tot + producten[product.Key] * product.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Dit product verkopen wij niet.");
                    }
                }
                boot = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Gelieve " + tot + " euro te betalen.");

            }
```